# Edit and automatically mask creditcard numbers on an image (windows environment)

Tags: opencv, ocr, tesseract, emgucv, google-vision

I have a system to which sometimes the users upload credit or debit card images. The idea is to make the credit card numbers non-human readable. The plan is to mask out the credit card numbers in the image automatically upon loading the image.

I am looking at the a possible solution that can be used in windows environment.(Do not want a cloud solution like google OCR at the moment).

I have looked at different options and different .net wrappers for OpenCV, Tesseract etc looks promising but everything fails miserably on .net environment.(note java script variants are not in considered at the moment due to compatibility on different mobile browsers and node options not looked into).

Since image received may contain the credicard image and it can be scanned in an angle with respect to the A4 paper. First the rectangle needs to be identified and the card numbers(digits) needs to be blured, cut or obfuscated).

Any pointers to working examples in .net environments
or any other environments is highly appreciated

Comment: Emgu CV and Google Vision API are the final candidates. Dev team is keen on moving to the Vision API due to its superior image recognition and co-ordinates locating abilities.

Answer (score 0):

Project for mobile platforms: https://github.com/card-io/card.io-dmz
You can create *.dll on C++ with algorithm implementation and use it from .net.

Comment: looking for a tool that can process image and edit or mask out all numbers in it.